# C# Show TreeNode ToolTip as long as TreeNode is hovered

Tags: c#, while-loop, tooltip, treenode, mouse-position

When a `TreeNode`in my `TreeView`is hovered, a `ToolTip` is supposed to show. And when the mouse leave the `TreeNode` the `ToolTip` should dissapear. I tried doing this by getting the `MousePosition` of `PontToClient()` and `Show()` the `ToolTip` as long as the `MousePosition` did not change. It works but it doesn't look good. The `ToolTip` dissapear or doesn't show if the mouse is moved just the slightest.

This gave a somewhat working result

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
    tip.ToolTipTitle = e.Node.Name;
    Point client = PointToClient(MousePosition);
    while (client == PointToClient(MousePosition))
    {
        tip.Show(e.Node.Nodes.Count.ToString(), this, PointToClient(MousePosition));
    }
    tip.Dispose();
}
```

Instead I'm trying to show the `ToolTip` as long as the `TreeNode` at the `MousePosition` is the same as the `TreeNode` that triggered the event. But now the `ToolTip` never shows?

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
    tip.ToolTipTitle = e.Node.Name;
    while (e.Node == treeView.GetNodeAt(MousePosition))
    {
        tip.Show(e.Node.Nodes.Count.ToString(), this, PointToClient(MousePosition));
    }
    tip.Dispose();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just realized that the this result in following exception?

```
treeView.GetNodeAt(MousePosition).Name
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`treeView.GetNodeAt(MousePosition)` returns `null`, so you can not access property `Name` from it.

`MousePosition` is position of mouse pointer on your screen, not on your control. So, lets assume your pointer in in the middle of screen, so coordinates would be like x: 1000, y: 500. But, `GetNodeAt()` expects coordinates in treeview, where, in example, first node is at x: 20 and Y: 50 coordinates.

You have to transform those coordinates to be relative to your treeview, something like this:

```
var point = treeView.PointToClient(MousePosition);
var node = treeView.GetNodeAt(point);
```

**UPDATE:**
In your second example, correct use would be:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
    tip.ToolTipTitle = e.Node.Name;
    while (e.Node == treeView.GetNodeAt(treeView.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
    {
        tip.Show(e.Node.Nodes.Count.ToString(), this, PointToClient(MousePosition));
    }
    tip.Dispose();
}
```

but, to simplify things (and avoid flickering, constant initialization of tooltip etc), I would move ToolTip declaration out of the method and put it into the form's scope, then show ToolTip on hover and hide it on mouse move.
Like this:

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();

private void treeView_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{

    tip.ToolTipTitle = e.Node.Name;
    tip.Show(e.Node.Nodes.Count.ToString(), this, PointToClient(MousePosition));

}

private void treeView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView.GetNodeAt(treeView.PointToClient(MousePosition)) == null)
        tip.Hide(this);
}
```